# Проблема с кодировкой в мемо

Tags: кодировка, delphi-7

Получаю код страницы таким образом :

`procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.ya.ru/'));
end;`

в мемо вместо русских символов кракозябры.
как исправить?

Comment: Utf8ToAnsi(IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.ya.ru/'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
  Memo1.Lines.Add(UTF8Decode(IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.ya.ru/')));
```

Comment: спасибо! работает.